# Create diagram Er sqlite database android studio

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, diagram, diagrams, erd

i have finished an android project. So i will create an Entity Relationship Diagram from my DbAdapter class in android studio.How can I obtain this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature in Android Studio to generate an entity/relationship diagram.